# directory sync: windows azure active directory sync tool ... will it erase O365 users if they do not exist on local AD?

Tags: azure, active-directory, single-sign-on, office365

search here showed no real answer.

we currently have around 90 users in O365. we are standing up a fresh new DC and i was wondering, if i run the windows azure directory sync tool wizard (assuming i have already activated directory sync in Azure), input all the credentials, will it look at my local AD and see there are no users there and sync to O365 essentially removing all the O365 users? i know it does not sync both ways so the O365 users won't be transferred which is fine. but will it wipe my O365 users?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it won't. It will try to soft match based on the proxyAddresses attribute in AD matching the values in O365. If there isn't a match, you'll end up with duplicates or export errors in Dirsync.

Comment: that is what i thought. i also noticed once the wizard is complete there are a lot of config options for the syncing. 

i am assuming powershell commands are the best way to export the O365 users into the new AD